# 'variable lengths differ' error when using "subset" in "lm"

Tags: r, regression, subset, linear-regression, lm

First day using R, so sorry if this question is obvious.

I'm trying to run a regression with both factor variables and numerical variables.

- `Diet` is a factor variable that goes from 1-10. I produced a new factor variable `Diet.Factor`.
- `Source` is another factor variable that can be A or B.
- I want to run a linear regression for `Weight` based on `Diet.Factor` for when `Source==A`.

Now,

```
lm(Weight~Diet.Factor,data=labdata)
```

works fine, but

```
lm(Weight~Diet.Factor,data=subset(labdata,Source=="A"))
```

gives

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Weight ~ Diet.Factor,  
  :variable lengths differ (found for 'Diet.Factor')
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the output of `str(labdata)`

Comment: How did you define `Diet.Factor`, is it a column of `labdata` or a new variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't have `Diet.Factor` column in your data frame `labdata`, but have it in the global environment, so that it is not subject to subsetting. This is the only possible cause.

Comment: New, so can't accept your question or upvote visibly but thanks.